# Цикл в оптимизации работает не корректно, не обновляются переменные

Tags: javascript

Выводится 10 раз одно и то же x1max, а в нормальном виде x1max должно уменьшаться, соответственно и функция которая должна функция Fmin должна стремиться к 30, а на деле она стремится к максимуму 330.

https://jsfiddle.net/y0q0xope/2/

```js
var x1min = 0;
var x1max = 10;
var x2min = 5;
var x2max = 15;
var x1 = [];
var x2 = [];
var x1_1 = [];
var x2_1 = [];
var f = [];
var k = 0;
var Fk = [];
var g1 = [];
var l = 0;

function compareNumeric(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}

function g(x1_0, x2_0) {
  return (x1_0 * x1_0) + (x2_0 * x2_0) + 5;
}

var Fmin = g(10, 7);


do {
  l++
  for (var i = 0; i <= 30; i++) {
    x1[i] = (x1min + (x1max - x1min) * Math.random());
    x2[i] = (x2min + (x2max - x2min) * Math.random());
    f[i] = g(x1[i], x2[i]);

  }



  g1 = f.sort(compareNumeric);

  if (g1[0] < Fmin) {
    for (var j = 0; j <= 30; j++) {
      if (g1[j] < Fmin) {
        Fk[j] = g1[j];
        x1_1[j] = x1[j];
        x2_1[j] = x2[j];
      }
    }
  }

  Fmin = g1[0];
  var x1_1_1 = x1_1.sort(compareNumeric);
  var x2_1_1 = x2_1.sort(compareNumeric);
  x1min = x1_1_1[0];
  x1max = x1_1_1[x1_1_1.length - 1];
  x2min = x2_1_1[0];
  x2max = x2_1_1[x2_1_1.length - 1];

  console.log(Fmin);
  console.log(x1max);
} while (l < 10)
```

Comment: [mcve] бы... Пока не сильно понятно что не так.

Comment: Он работает, там задана функция вида f(x1,x2) = x1^2 + x2^2 + 5, минимальное ее значение это 30, вот в коде происходит оптимизация, на первом шаге все хорошо, но когда надо обновить, x1min,x1max и x2, они обновляются раз и все и потом  они уже не изменяются 
интервал x1min..x1max, должен уменьшаться от 0..10 до 0.. 0.1, с х2 тоже самое от 5..15 до 5..5.1